# Is it correct to say $\int dy = \int f'(x) dx$, or does it need to be $\int {dy \over dx} dx = \int f'(x) dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, differential-forms

If I have the derivative, $${df \over dx} = f'(x)$$

To integrate, is it correct to separate the $df$ and $dx$ differentials:
$${df \over dx} \hphantom{.} = \hphantom{....}f'(x)\hphantom{.}$$
$$\hphantom{...} df \hphantom{.} = \hphantom{....}f'(x) dx$$
$$\int \Big{[} df \Big{]} = \int \Big{[} f'(x) dx \Big{]}$$

Or can it only be done like this:

$${df \over dx} = f'(x)$$
$$\int \Big{[}{df \over dx}\Big{]} dx = \int \Big{[}{f'(x)}\Big{]} dx$$

(Or are both correct?) I am asking because recently I learned if you have a total differential $df = y\hphantom{.}  dx + x\hphantom{.}  dy$, you can't just integrate like this $\int df = \int y\hphantom{.} dx + \int x\hphantom{.} dy$ as this would get you $f(x,y) = 2xy$ instead of $xy$.

Instead, you have to integrate like $(\int y dx + \int x\hphantom{.} {dy \over dx}dx) \rightarrow  xy + c(y) + 0 = xy + c$. And I'm wondering if that also applies to the $df$ on the LHS, where you would have to integrate with ${df \over dx}{dx}$ instead of just $df$.

Thanks.

Comment: The notation $\frac{df}{dx}$ is shorthand for $\frac{d}{dx}(f)$ the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$. $df$ is not a mathematical object in its own right. The rearrangement of $\frac{df}{dx}=f'(x)$ into $df=f'(x)dx$ is an abuse of notation, which correctly alludes to how one 'undoes' the differentiation by integrating with respect the variable that the function was differentiated by (This is part of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus).

Comment: @JustinBenfield You are quite wrong. Learn about differential forms before you proclaim that "$df$ is not a mathematical object in its own right."

Comment: Notice that the notation $\int dy$ is shorthand for $\int 1 dy=y+c$. $\frac{df}{dx}$ is not a "fraction" with numerator $df$ and denominator $dx$, though the notation is chosen this way purposefully to invoke some fraction rules and intuition that carries across.

Comment: @TedShifrin One can, of course, give $df$ a mathematical meaning, but at the point that one first encounters $\frac{df}{dx}$ in a basic Calculus course, this has not been done (To see how this can be done in a more general context, see: Differential Calculus section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form). See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function

Comment: @JustinBenfield You don't need to lecture me on how to define differential forms. I'm suggesting that you refrain from making blatantly *false* statements with no qualifications.

Comment: I think we can agree that when $f$ is declared "a function of $x$", (what is $x$? a local coordinate? a "variable"? needs context...), the notation $df$ _may_ be legitimate or not, depending on context. (As in spoken English/natural-language, grammar errors do not necessarily invalidate the content, also...)

Comment: @TedShifrin The statement is true to the definitions that OP appears to know. Which is why I gave the comment that I did. In the context of the definitions given in a standard first year calculus course, $df$ does not have a mathematical meaning. It can, of course, be given one, (which I provided those references for the OP to read if they wished to see/know how that is done, I am not trying to lecture you on what you clearly already know).

Comment: It becomes even more confusing, since differential forms aren't even the only way of interpreting $\int \,dy$, not to mention the common abuse of notation in stochastic calculus.

Answer (score 4):

Its just a notation, you can use $df$ to mean $f'(x)dx$ if you like, but its not an standard notation for a basic calculus course. Some areas where this notation could appear as a standard notation:

1. In differential geometry, $df$ represent what is called a differential form or the differential of a smooth map.
2. In measure theory, if $f$ is a function of bounded variation between real or complex finite dimensional vector spaces, then $df$ represents a complex measure (this notation is commonly used in probability theory).
3. In an hyperreal setting $df$ represents an infinitesimal (indeed, in this setting, the expression $df/dx$ is a quotient of infinitesimal numbers, where $dx\neq 0$ and $df$ is just a notation for the infinitesimal $f'(x)dx$).

There are other places where this notation can appear, but they are rarer (in general something like this appear in alternative theories for differential geometry or calculus).